# Ubuntu search - how to change to the IDEA of the updated installation

Tags: search

## Question

I downloaded and manually installed IDEA 2019. I want the Search to find the new one.

```
$ ls -lrt /opt/idea/
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Oct 29  2018 idea-community-2018.2.5
drwxr-xr-x 8 masa masa 4096 Jul 23 14:05 idea-IC-191.7479.19
```

[image]

How can I stop Search to switch from finding the old one and to find and launch the new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the IntelliJ from the console.

For your setup this should be:
/opt/idea/idea-IC-191.7479.19/bin/idea.sh

When started use this to recreate a desktop entry:
Tools -> Create Desktop Entry...

After this it should be visible in the search.